# How to work with stan results that exceed 10GB

Tags: r, snow, stan

I have a model that is predicting a time-series. So I have just 5 parameter - which I then use to calculate the time-series as transformed parameters producing a 7200x3 matrix - which will then be compared with the observations.

So far so good - works as expected when just doing 100 iterations. 
But now I used SNOW to parallelize this calculation to create 6x1000 iteration. Took an hour - but looks fine. Only problem is I can no longer load the resulting rdata file. It is 11GB in size - so that might be it.

I will need to increase the number of simulations - so I need to find a way to work with data this size. How do other people deal with this problem?

**Code**

(trying to make a simple example - so it will be readable)

*R script*

```
library(rstan)
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)

model.c <- stanc(file="3c_model.stan")
model.comp <- stan_model(stanc_ret=model.c) 
cl <- makeCluster(6, type="SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
num_chains <- 6
parallel_fit <- foreach(i = 1:num_chains,.packages='rstan') %dopar% {
  s <- sampling(model.comp, data=stan.list, chains=1, iter= 1000)
}
fits <- sflist2stanfit(parallel_fit)
stopCluster(cl)
```

*relevant part of the model*

```
functions { 
  vector evolve(vector pre, real inp, real p1){
     vector[3] out;
     out[1] <- pre[1] + pre[2]/p1;
     out[2] <- pre[2] + pre[3]/p1;
     out[3] <- pre[3]/p1 + inp;
  }
}

data {
  int<lower=1> N ;
  real<lower=0> y[N] ;
  real<lower=0> inp[N] ;
}

parameters { 
  vector<lower=0, upper=5000>[3] init_ss; 
  real<lower=0, upper=60> p1;
}

transformed parameters {      
  vector[3] state[N];
  state[1] <- init_ss;
  for (i in 2:N){
    state[i] <- evolve(state[i-1], inp[i-1] ,p1);
  }
}

model {   
  p1 ~ gamma(1, 10);
  init_ss ~ gamma(1,100);
  for (i in 100:N){
    if (y[i] >0 ) 
      y[i] ~ normal(state[i][1], 1) ;
  }
}
```

*update*

I was successful reorganizing the code following the example in the [Modeling Language Manual](http://mc-stan.org/manual.html) p41 - now the state space is no longer stored. Unfortunately I still need the trajectories (at least at this development stage). So I will leave this open in hope someone has a clever solution.

Comment: Save the data in chunks or save as an ASCII file and read in chunks or use a database or use the bigmemory package.

Comment: Post your code. Most likely you don't need to actually save all the simulation details.

Comment: @Roland That was my first idea as well. From what I was seeing I would need to do this during the call to `sampling` and I'm not confident how to make this. Also it would be most helpful if I was still able to use rstans functions like `traceplot` for now.

Comment: if it is 11 GB the easiest would be to just buy a bit of extra RAM 4 modules of 4GB would cost around 100$/€. a day of work would probably cost more...

Comment: @phonixor - actually my machine would have enough RAM for this. R is crashing on loading the file - but not during the simulation. Also I fear I will eventually need to increase the number of iterations by the factor 10 - so way to much for regular RAM.

Comment: I would start by specifying the `sample_file` argument to `sampling` so that the results are saved to the disk for safekeeping (i.e. in case of crashes). Also, the `thin` argument might ultimately be necessary. If you have enough RAM to analyze the results of one chain at a time, you could do that using the `read_stan_csv` function. For analysis that requires all the chains, you would probably have to write some custom stuff along the lines of what @Roland suggested.

Comment: @Ben Goodrich s info basically solves it for me. If you put it as answer I'll accept that.